# Running out of registers and having trouble in Y86

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, y86

I am currently writing functions using an educational assembly language called Y86, AT&T syntax and am trying to accomplish/get around something this doesn't support. I want to add a number to a value stored in memory and for some stupid reason you can only use addl to add to a register. I don't know why this is.

Inside a function I want to do something such as this and don't know how:

```
addl $1, -4(ebp)
```

Also, I seem to have a problem of running out of registers. Maybe it's because I don't know how to make room for storing local variables. I have heard thought there is a concept where registers are saved by the caller and callee. I would greatly appreciate any commands that are equal to what's above but in Y86. Also any tips on saving registers would be great! THANK YOU! I know looking over this stuff is a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

In x86 and Y86 too registers are can be pushed to stack by using `push` and popped from stack by using `pop`. Like this:

```
push %ax ; push ax into stack

; some code here that may overwrite ax.

pop %ax  ; pop ax from stack
```

x86 has a limited number of register, so many times one needs to use memory for some of the variables.

To create space in stack for local variables, you need to create a stack frame. See [What is stack frame in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699283/what-is-stack-frame-in-assembly) .