# Is this how the stack works? Intel X86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, reverse-engineering, stack-memory

I am learning Intel X86 Assembly and reverse engineering as I want to create game cheats.

I’m trying to understand memory and how the stack works. I know it’s a LIFO and some people say think of it as a stack of books where you add to the top and take out from the top. But instead of the books going upwards do you have to visualise it going downwards?

```
For example:

push 1
push 2 
push 3
pop x

push would equal: 

1
2
3 <- esp

pop would equal:

1
2 <- esp
```

Comment: "do you have to visualise it going downwards" what difference does it make?

Comment: It depends on your cultural background. Do you write from left to right or vice versa? When something grows, does it grow up or down? For instance when you dig a well. The direction of your innervision doesn't matter much, but **be consistent**.

Comment: You say that you want to understand how the stack works. I am going to toot my own horn and suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699283/what-is-stack-frame-in-assembly/3700219 -- it covers stack frames, and shows how the stack pointer is adjusted and manipulated.

Comment: On a sheet of paper that is lying on a horizontal desk, which way is up and which way is down? :)

Comment: If there are symbols that can be recognised as letters only from one direction / the whole sheet makes sense from only one direction -- that can determine the 'up/down/left/right' orientation. Otherwise up/down requires gravitation.

Answer (score 3):

Vertical up/down are not the only possible visualizations — we can use horizontal as well:

```
    lower addresses         ...         higher addresses 
      +----------------------------------------------+
      |  (free stack)  | 3 | 2 | 1 |    (in use)     |
      +----------------------------------------------+
                         ^
                         |
                        esp
```

This visualization allows structs to be viewed in a "forwards" direction, left to right; argument lists that are pushed last to first as well.  Push expands the stack leftward, which still feels pretty natural.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You can basically visualize the stack however you like. The more often encountered way to represent stack is that a stack is said to grow down, from higher addresses to lower addresses.

To support this narrative, stack is often visualized as

```
+------------------+ <- top of memory = 0x10000
| used_stack       | 
|                  |
+------------------+
| local variables  | <- top of stack = 0xff00 
|   [red zone]     |    <- red zone is guaranteed to be unused
| unused memory    |       by exception handlers
|                  |
| ---------------- |
|    HEAP          | <- dynamically allocated memory
+------------------+ address = 0x0000
```

Personally I found this unintuitive, since this reverses the order in which other memory structures or arrays are typically presented. There's no *down* in a CPU.

```
 | offset     description.    hex dump
 +-----------+----------------+------------------------
 | 0         | char header[4] | 01 02 03 04
 | 8         | int16 width    | 08 00
 | 10        | int16 height   | 04 00 
 | 12        | int32 size     | 20 00 00 00

 vs.
 struct FileFormat {
     char header[4];
     int16_t width{8};
     int16_t height{4};
     int32_t size{32};
 };
```

When stack is visualized as a stalactite (hangs like an icicle) it physically grows down, but it loses the connection to real life stacks, as in stack of plates or books, which grow up.

```
           A                                    B
    +-------------+                     +--------------+
    | ceil of stk | <-high addresses    |  unused      | <-small addresses
    | 20 00 00 00 |                     |              |
    | 08 00 04 00 |                     |              |
    | 01 02 03 04 | <-- top of stack -> | 01 02 03 04  |
    |             |                     | 08 00 04 00  |
    |             |                     | 20 00 00 00  |
    | unused/heap |                     |bottom of stck|
    +-------------+                     +--------------+
```

The format A is more convenient at least when you have a written text like

```
 push 1
 push 2
 push 3
```

In the style A, this is represented as is, in style B, the values are reversed.

Comment: *There's no down in a CPU* - There are high vs. low addresses.  I always picture memory with low addresses at the bottom, thus picture the stack like a stalactite.  Once you reserve a block of it, then within that block you can have a normal struct.  And yeah I sometimes find it weird that source code lists low-address elements first (like C arrays/structs, or asm `dd 1,2,3`).  But usually I'm not bouncing back and forth between ways of thinking about memory very often.

Comment: It's the same challenge with thinking of SIMD vectors the way Intel draws them, so left shifts are actually left, which is helpful for seeing how `pslld 16` can move data in similar ways to `pslldq 2`.   (The stack equivalent to mixing sizes like that is if you mix 2x `push word` with `pop dword`, you can combine 2 words into a dword, so endianness is also involved.  Not that I'd recommend that outside of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78972/30206), normally `shl edx,16`/`mov dx,ax`)

Comment: To be fully coherent, everything would need to be either little endian or big endian in all scales - and the stack pointer should move respectively. I do remember C64 memory charts being represented high addresses top, but then that conflicts with how the software people have implemented e.g. hex dumps and disassemblers, as western languages are read/written from top to bottom. I do visualise memory in hex dump order and struggle indeed with 'left shifts' of SIMD registers.

Answer (score -2):

The "growing down" is simply used to match how most operating systems set up x86 stacks. The hardware is capable of working with stacks that grow in either direction but the operating system sets the CPU to have the stack use lower and lower memory addresses as more items are pushed onto the stack.

Having stacks grow down was a particularly useful choice when systems were single-CPU and would generally be running single-threaded processes in control of the entire system. The stack was placed at the top of available memory and the heap at the bottom and they would each grow to meet the other. In modern multi-threaded processes it doesn't work quite so simply, each thread requires an independent stack, although the heap can be shared by the entire process. The thread will have some maximum size chosen when the thread is created and if that space is exhausted some kind of error condition will need to be generated. Note, however, that 'thread' and 'process' in this context is entirely up to the OS design, the CPU is simply informed what code to run.

Comment: The direction of stack-growth isn't settable on x86, AFAIK, unlike some other ISAs.  So "*The hardware is capable of working with stacks that grow in either direction*" - would only be true if you avoid `call`/`ret` and `push`/`pop` and any other stack instructions!  Then yes, user-space stacks could grow upward on x86.  Kernel stacks still need to grow down because the CPU itself will push interrupt-return context onto them.  By contrast, MIPS never implicitly uses any register as a stack pointer, just putting stuff in registers for the kernel to push if it wants.