# Why does the compiler reserve just 0x10 bits for an int?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f()
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}

void f(int i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    f(0x123456);
}
```

I compiled it using `g++`, then disassembled it using `objdump -Mintel -d` and I got the following for the main function:

```
 08048733 <main>:
 8048733:   55                      push   ebp
 8048734:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 8048736:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
 8048739:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
 804873c:   e8 9b ff ff ff          call   80486dc <_Z1fv>
 8048741:   c7 04 24 56 34 12 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x123456
 8048748:   e8 bb ff ff ff          call   8048708 <_Z1fi>
 804874d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 8048752:   c9                      leave  
 8048753:   c3                      ret
```

Now, the reserved space in the stack is 16 bits (0x10, in line 8048739), while an int (on my machine) is 32 bits. This can't be because of optimization because the number 0x123456 won't fit into 16 bits. So why doesn't the compiler reserve enough space?

Comment: That `0x10` **bytes** not bits.

Comment: @Mat in this case, it's too much memory!

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? which compiler version?

Comment: @Leeor I think so - I didn't specify any thing. I will post soon the code with no optimization.

Comment: @Leeor the code with no optimization is the same.

Comment: Semi-related: [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009070)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it's been pointed out that it's 0x10 bytes (not bits). it's 16 bytes because gcc keeps stack 16-byte aligned for x86. From GCC manual:

> -mstackrealign Realign the stack at entry. On the Intel x86, the -mstackrealign option generates an alternate prologue and epilogue that realigns the run-time stack if necessary. This supports mixing
>   legacy codes that keep 4-byte stack alignment with modern codes that
>   keep 16-byte stack alignment for SSE compatibility. See also the
>   attribute force_align_arg_pointer, applicable to individual functions.
>
> -mpreferred-stack-boundary=num Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num byte boundary. If
>   -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits).

Comment: GCC only realigns the stack on entry to `main` in 32-bit builds.  Other functions are assumed to be called with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` alignment.  (On i386 Linux, the current ABI even *guarantees* 16-byte alignment before a call, so `ESP % 16 == 12` on function entry; some other OSes didn't change their 32-bit ABI when Linux/gcc did.  See [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001) re: i386 and amd64)

Answer (score 0):

*I am not sure myself but I can try to help*
`sub    esp,0x10` is not done to get the reserved space of the int(32bits) on the stack. Instead the first 4 assembly instructions are merely a compiler optimization used to free up the ebp register to be used as a general purposed register.

[Read more about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020825/1675971)

The actual assembly involving the integer is `mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x123456`.

Hope it helps.
Digvijay

Comment: so, if `sub esp,0x10` is to do with optimization, when do I reserve space for the int?

Comment: So from the link, ESP is now pointing to next available free memory. Now the literal "ox123456" is actually stored in the code section. Which is then copied over to the memory using the 6th assembly instruction.